# How to edit swf file link without fla file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, edit, fla

How to edit flash file (.swf) without .fla file ? I got banner in swf file and a need to make something like that:

when user click on that banner he will be redirected to an url (for example http://www.google.com/).

Comment: Have you just tried wrapping the swf in an achor tag?

Comment: I don't think so. You could try decompiling the swf, changing the link and then using the new swf. Obviously, this is to be done only if you have a license to modify the swf. :)

Comment: How i can decompile the swf file in Flash Pro ? Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at clicktag. 
http://www.flashmagazine.com/news/detail/solving_clicktag_in_flash9/

```
private function onClick(e : MouseEvent) : void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(stage.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG));
}
```

Comment: Note that setting a clicktag will only work if the flash banner was made to support one.